# Inserting leading and trailing space in a regex match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I googled about my present problem. My problem is related to regex.

I have text, example,

```
   Before call<u+1f602><u+1f602>
```

I want unicode to be separated from any leading and trailing characters i.e. I want my output as:

```
   Before call <u+1f602><u+1f602>
```

Leading and trailing characters can be anything: a-z,0-9,!,? etc.

Comment: Do you want to insert a space before and after characters other than `a-zA-Z0-9!?` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://ideone.com/yBmuJM)?